# Transfer data from 1 column to another from different table with middle table as link

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

I have 3 tables with table `C.Bid` referencing to `B.id` and `B.Aid` referencing to `A.id`. I want to transfer data from columns in table A to table C but having issues with the sql.

[image]

Heres what i did

```
UPDATE contact_address,
(SELECT contact_master.id , contact_master.address, 
contact_branch.contact_master_id, contact_branch.id
FROM contact_master
INNER JOIN contact_branch ON contact_master.id = 
contact_branch.contact_master_id)
SET contact_address.address = contact_master.address
WHERE contact_address.contact_branch_id = contact_branch.id;
```

My understanding from the [UPDATE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html), is the comma can be used to separate different column we want to add in the select statement.

How do i transfer these data column using referenced attribute in the middle table? error im getting is

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET contact_address.address = contact_master.address
> where contact_address.cont' at line 5

I already have the rows of data on table C where i insert them using these query.

```
INSERT INTO `contact_branch` (contact_master_id)
SELECT `id` FROM `contact_master`;

INSERT INTO `contact_address` (contact_branch_id)
SELECT `id` FROM `contact_branch`;
```

Comment: Where are you adding in the join element? Can you show the full SQL with this join included?

Comment: Are you really inserting or updating address column on existing rows in the contact_address table?

Comment: Provide complete example. See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: I did work work on it and edited the question details, currently updating the rows @OluwafemiSule

Comment: ive edited the question with more info, thanks for the advice @A.Steer

Comment: ive edited the question with more info, thanks for the advice @Akina

Comment: `UPDATE .. FROM` is MS SQL (SQL Server) syntax which is not legal in MySQL. Study [MySQL Reference Manual/../UPDATE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html), use Multiple-table syntax.

Comment: PS. Also your statement is not legal in MS SQL too - you mix different clauses (JOIN is placed after WHERE) which is not allowed.

Comment: Ive went through the multiple table syntax and i think the rewriting subquery is the best for my case but im getting a few more errors. Ive edited the question, I see, ill read more on MS SQL and Mysql differences, thanks @Akina

Comment: Do not use comma-style joining, use explicit JOIN syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, giving `AS` to subquery, and `AS` for middle table (conatct_branch) `id` so it won't confuse the program.

```
UPDATE contact_address,
(SELECT contact_master.*, contact_branch.id AS cId
FROM contact_master
INNER JOIN contact_branch ON contact_master.id = contact_branch.contact_master_id) AS subque
SET contact_address.address = subque.address
WHERE contact_address.contact_branch_id = subque.cId;
```